# "flutter pub add" reported an error——“Expected to find project root in current working directory.”

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3odE.png)
I wish to import the package: flutter_displaymode/flutter_displaymode.dart'
But the above error occurred when I ran the flutter instruction using cmd. The development environment is Android Studio

I tried to close Android Studio, and also tried to use the cd command to switch the path to the root directory of flutter, but it still reported an error

Comment: Please add the error message as a plain text and remove the image. Also it's better to add a link to the package you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to implement the dependency is wrong. Remember that dependency packages go in the project directory.

The message `Expected to find project root in current working directory` is because the project directory is not found to add the package.

What you should do is open the projector directory in terminal and run `flutter pub add flutter_displaymode`

Here's more information how to add more dependencies.
https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#using-packages

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're in the directory of your flutter project folder that contains pubspec.yaml and then run flutter pub add <your_required_file>